# Heroku Deployment - Not found: '/'

Tags: python, heroku, deployment

I am brand new to Heroku deployments and am attempting to launch a Python 2.7 app using the service. I followed their deployment guide step by step, but every time I run "heroku open" I am given a 404 error due to " Not found: '/' ".

I believe that the error lies in the IP address, when I run the local server it currently listens on the default http://0.0.0.0:8080 address. My run code, from main:

```
# Expose WSGI app (so gunicorn can find it)
application = bottle.default_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   bottle.run(application, host=os.getenv('IP', '0.0.0.0'), 
   port=os.getenv('PORT', '8080'))
```

I have ensured that my app accounts for heroku's dynamic porting, does anyone have any other ideas what is wrong?

Thank you, please let me know if I can provide any further information.

Comment: Post relevant code as text in your question, do not provide links.

Comment: Please cut your code down to the minimum amount that demonstrates the problem, and put it in the question.

Comment: @kindall apologies for the poor formatting, I have (hopefully) fixed that error

Comment: Looking at [the documentation](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.run) it appears that `run()` takes the port as a number, while you're passing a string. Try `port=int(os.getenv('PORT', '8080')))`